# RFM Site Contract Dissolve

Tags: contracts, royalty-free

Hey all!

On royalty free music sites - how does the composer normally remove their content from said site when he/she wants to reel their material back in?

There has to be a contractual clause between the parties that provides direction in this particular case. I would imagine its quite common.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

First guess, written request to the company. Even if you speak to someone on the phone about it, they're probably going to want a written formal request for their records. It helps protect you legally as well, so I would send it in via certified mail/signature confirmation so that you have some record as to when it was received.

Comment: @Shaun Thanks! Have you ever seen an agreement that let the artist purchase the dissolve of an exclusive contract - If the contract stated that the exclusivity was only referring to the online sale of the material?

Comment: @C3Sound - I've never been involved with the royalty free music market. I just know that that bit is fairly typical standard operating procedure. I shouldn't speculate, because it would be only that...speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I have never uploaded stuff to a royalty free site but I have read a lot of the different contracts.  Usually, they require you to formally email them a request to remove your pieces from the site so that they are no longer for sale.  You cannot get back the pieces of music you have already sold you can only choose to no longer sell them.  It is apart of the license that the buyers agree to, they can use it forever.  Imagine buying some royalty free music and then getting an email that you have to delete it and never use it again.  I would guess that people only put certain pieces up on those sites and keep their best ones for other hopeful sales.

Comment: @Britt Thanks Britt! No, I was talking about just the companies ability to sell the track online. Haha totally, theres no way you could do it to the extreme you mentioned!
